# java.lang.InterruptedException While Trying to Get Location

Tags: blackberry

Here is my code:

```
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
        Location currentLocation = locationProvider.getLocation(300);
```

It throws the exception at the third line. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question? Looking at the API it does not say that getInstance() throws an InterruptedException. However, it does say that getLocation() throws InterruptedException. Could it be this line that is causing the Exception?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. It is third line.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace then? Again, looking at the api says that getLocation throws InterruptedException "if the operation is interrupted by calling reset() from another thread" are there several threads calling getLocation at the same time?

Comment: No there is not any other threads. I think I figured it out. When I was in an open are, it works. It may be about GPS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When I am in a closed area GPS cannot receive data and throws InterruptedException.

Answer (score 2):

Do you run your application in the simulator? If yes ,then you have to change the IT policy.
Go to Simulate select Set IT Policy & GPS Location as given below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this will help you.. :)